# Send a variable from my server to my client

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, get

when I console.log(response.data) it is undefined. Why is that?

I already tried res.send and res.json but they both just return undefined...

Should I be changing something in my client or in my server

Server side

```
//server js file
app.get("/updateCart", (req, res) => {
    //get items from cart
    dataServiceAuth.findUser("joe")
    .then((user) => {
      res.json(user[0]); //I know user[0] has a value I console.log it to the screen
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("ERROR. Can't find user")
    });
});
```

Client side

```
//client file
$("document").ready(function () {
fetch("/updateCart", {method: "GET"}).then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
app.get('/getItems' (req, res) => {
    let x = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
    res.send(x)
})
```

OR

```
app.get('/getItems' (req, res) => {
    let x = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
    res.json(x)
})
```

Client.js

```
var myItems;
fetch("/getItems", method: "GET").then(response => {
  myItems = response.data;
});
```

Comment: the myItems variable is undefined. Do you know why that is? I tried both res.send and json. I even tried to print the response.data and thats undefined too

Comment: because your data is not a valid json. `objects` should always have key and value. You could try changing your `x = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1];`

Comment: I changed it and its still undefined. Really I am making a call from my database and I am trying to send back a "user" object. I just put x=[1,2,3] as an example so it was shorter and easier for someone to read

Comment: Check your network tab in dev console if the api is returning anything. If not, then there is something wrong on the server side.

Comment: I checked it and it's all fine. I reposted my question and thats the exact code I am using. Does anything look wrong with it?

Comment: Add a `console.log(user[0])` before `res.json(user[0]);` and check if user[0] exist in your server

Comment: ya it has a value I just rechecked it right now. I even made a an array like what you suggested var x = [2, 3, 1] and still returned undefined

Comment: Could you open the `networks tab` in the dev console. Select the correct `api` and check the response in the `preview` tab?

Comment: I checked the updateCart and the response shows my object i'm trying to get. what does that mean?

Comment: response.json()
           .then((data) => {console.log(data.cart);})

Comment: that returns the data. Thanks for your help tho means alot!